# Is it Good practice to store larg Data in xml file at application level to save round trip to database?

Tags: xml

i have situation where i have to store some data (e.g Ticket Numbers like '110022','12313' not in sequence ) and every time i need to check weather that number is in used or not , currently we are storing all these number in SQL Database table but those data are very large of 85,000 around so i thought of saving that data in xml format at application level rather than at database and saving hit to database table because in current situation we are getting server slowness issue because of search function which hit to database just to check the ticket number is exist or not ,at same time if new number come i need to save that number in xml file for future check condition please suggest me if you have any better alternative to resole this issue ...   technology i am using asp.net and sql server ..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: If you need to do an extra query for each row you want to investigate, this is not how you would do it. Try to merge/join the data from the beginning. Also keep in mind, unless the files are on a ramdisk, they are slower than database.